# Home automation database

Tags: mysql, web-applications, automation, arduino, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a new home automation project. In a nutshell, I have some Particle Photons controlling lights, an Arduino controlling the security system (door keypad, motion sensors) and some IR devices talking to Raspberry Pi that is doing some text-to-speech. I want to add a database with an web app that would let me control everything when I'm away.

I could probably do it on a Godaddy MySql server without any problem, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing this. If I host my own server, I could probably do local network communication. But since I just have a Celeron, would it be slower ? Would MySql be the best database for my project ? 
When the code is going to be release, I want to include [Mycroft](https://mycroft.ai/) for controlling everything vocally. 
I just want some leads and idea for my project.

If you want to know more about my project, let me know !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> But since I just have a Celeron, would it be slower? Would MySql be the best database for my project ?

It depends on your non-functional requirements, for example, how many parallel connections, inserts, updates, deletes, selects you are planning?

Definitely, Celeron can be host for mysql-server, but maybe, you can use even simpler database, for example, Sqlite which is default solution in android world:)
Please add some performance requirements and maybe even performance profile of your application.

Comment: No many I think. Maybe a couple from the raspberry pi connected to the Arduino for the authentification (check if code entered is valid, what is the name of the user and what they have access to/preference). I don't really have any specific requirements since I'm not sure how I'm going to build the whole system. I'm not sure either how I'm going to build the app, I want to be able to control the lights, the IR devices, lock/unlock, manage (add/delete) users and there access, and maybe I'll add some other features along the way. I'm gonna take a look Sqlite, thanks !

Comment: How much time approximatly would it take to a raspberry pi to make a MySql query to a local DB host on a Celeron ? I would pass the code entered on the keypad and get back the user name and a couple of variables.

Comment: It depends. But if table was small or with proper indexes and it would be low parallel connection it should be very fast (some milliseconds). But you can easily test this scenario. Install mysql on you celeron-server, create some sample data and then create some typical load with help of some script language like python, php or ruby. And measure response time